D-ITG 2.8.1 (.win binaries) ITGSend command with '-sp' port not working binding issue
When I input the command: "ITGSend -a 192.168.2.2 -sp 9400 -rp 32769 -C 1000 -u 500 1000 -t 20000 -l send_log_file" on my windows cmd line I get the following error:
flowSender: No error
Could not bind a new socket. Flow ID: 1
Error - FlowSender interrupted by an error
Finished sending packets of Flow ID: 1

On the receiver end the receiver log is not correct at all after inputting that command.
The command works without a '-sp' specified, but the send log is incorrect with it producing a log which sends from: (sender ip), to: (sender ip) when it should be from: (sender ip), to: (destination ip). Works as it should with receiver log without '-sp'.
I need this to work as I have to follow the examples from the D-ITG 2.8.1 manual.
I've tried things like setting an inbound and outbound port on the firewall settings, but to no avail.
I am completely stuck. Please, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
